# Simulator build for facebook app

Tags: ios, terminal

I need to have a permission from facebook for an app i am creating. For that a simulator build should be present to send it to them. I followed the steps as per facebook says but i dont get  the build. The process gets failed.What am i doing wrong. I have attached a screenshot showing what my code looks like.

I get the error:
    `xcodebuild: error: The directory /Users/admin does not contain an Xcode project.`

[image: The screenshot displays how tried to get the build using terminal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the `cd` command.

Try

```
cd ..
```

instead.